# Is there a way to use reflection to load a .NET Framework DLL to load in a .NET standard 2.0 application?

Tags: c#, .net-standard-2.0, .net-4.8

I'm loading DLLs via reflection into my .NET 6.0 application.  One of them relies on a third party DLL that is built for .NET framework.

If I use the DLL as a reference, there is no problem.

If I load via reflection while still having the DLL as a reference, there is no problem. (not much point in loading via reflection and having the DLL be a reference)

If I load via reflection without the DLL reference I get a 'Could not load file or assembly 'MccDaq, Version=2.9.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a37eefcf5c6ca10a'. The system cannot find the file specified.'

Loading via reflection

```
using System.Reflection;

namespace MCCTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private dynamic mydaq;
        private Assembly instDLL;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string curDir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            this.instDLL = Assembly.LoadFile($@"C:\junk\MCCTest\MCCWrapper\bin\Debug\net6.0-windows\MCCWrapper.dll");
            var instType = instDLL.GetType($"MCCWrapper.DAQ");

            mydaq = Activator.CreateInstance(instType) ;
            mydaq.open();

        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.textBox1.Text = mydaq.measure();
        }
    }

}
```

The DLL

```
namespace MCCWrapper
{
    public class DAQ
    {

        private MccDaq.MccBoard DaqBoard;
        MccDaq.ErrorInfo ULStat;
        private IntPtr MemHandle = IntPtr.Zero;
        string _resourceName;
        public string resourceName
        {
            get => _resourceName;
            set => _resourceName = value;
        }
        public void open()
        {
            clsErrorDefs.ReportError = MccDaq.ErrorReporting.PrintAll;
            clsErrorDefs.HandleError = MccDaq.ErrorHandling.StopAll;
            ULStat = MccDaq.MccService.ErrHandling
                (clsErrorDefs.ReportError, clsErrorDefs.HandleError);
            DaqBoard = new MccDaq.MccBoard(0);
        }
        public string measure()
        {

            short dataValue;
            float DataValueF;
            MccDaq.Range Range = MccDaq.Range.Bip10Volts;

            ULStat = DaqBoard.AIn(0, Range, out dataValue);
            ULStat = DaqBoard.ToEngUnits(Range, dataValue, out DataValueF);

            return DataValueF.ToString();
        }
    }

    public class clsErrorDefs
    {
        public static MccDaq.ErrorReporting ReportError;
        public static MccDaq.ErrorHandling HandleError;
        public static bool GeneralError;

        public static void DisplayError(MccDaq.ErrorInfo ErrCode)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show
                ("Cannot run sample program. Error reported: " +
                ErrCode.Message, "Unexpected Universal Library Error",
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            GeneralError = true;
        }

    }
}
```

I've also tried loading the third-party DLL into the .NET6.0 app via reflection and its no problem.

Comment: IIRC you don't need to have the third party DLL as referece, but the DLL file has to be physically present either on the project/application folder, or in one of the system folders

Comment: I think you may be right, but I put the 3rd party dll in the same folder as the app and wrapper dll and it still says can't be found.

How can I see where its looking for the DLL?

I also tried loading just the third-party dll through reflection and it worked.  Unfortunately I need the wrapper.

Comment: That depends on how your wrapper references it. If in your wrapper, in the reference properties "local copy" is true it will look on the local folder of the program; otherwise it will look on the system folders

Comment: I sprinkled it everywhere.  I think the actual problem is that its loading just .netstandard2.0 system rather than linking the old one for framework.  I think it knows to do this when loading directly, but not when loading in a wrapper.  I'll cross post to MSDN.